# Trim string in MS access query

Tags: ms-access

please help me to fix the below query.

I wanted to trim space in between the string. I have column called Name and it has spaces in between. For instance in data source The name format is “John   Steve   Miller” (more than one space in between) and I want to trim it as “John Steve Miller”( with only one space). Thank you in Advance

Comment: Are there 2 spaces between each name part? Try Replace() function. `Replace(fieldname, "  ", " ")`. Might not show it, but there are 2 spaces in the first argument string. Name is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as name for anything.

Comment: Try this ... `trim(replace(name, '  ', ' ' ))`

Comment: This function worked for me. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you could use the `Replace` function to replace every pair of two spaces with a single space:

```vb
?Replace("John  Steve Miller", "  ", " ")
John Steve Miller
```

This will not account for instances in which you have more than two consecutive spaces, e.g.:

```vb
?Replace("John   Steve Miller", "  ", " ")
John  Steve Miller
```

```vb
?Replace("John    Steve Miller", "  ", " ")
John  Steve Miller
```

As such, I would suggest the following function to handle any number of consecutive spaces:

```vb
Function TrimSpace(strStr As String) As String
    Dim strRtn As String: strRtn = Replace(strStr, "  ", " ")
    If strRtn = strStr Then
        TrimSpace = Trim(strRtn)
    Else
        TrimSpace = TrimSpace(strRtn)
    End If
End Function
```

```vb
?TrimSpace("John  Steve Miller")
John Steve Miller
```

```vb
?TrimSpace("John   Steve  Miller")
John Steve Miller
```

```vb
?TrimSpace("John    Steve   Miller")
John Steve Miller
```

```vb
?TrimSpace("John     Steve    Miller")
John Steve Miller
```

Comment: This will definitely help my requirement for another field. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @PradyPradeep You're welcome - please mark my answer as the solution if it sufficiently answered your question, so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site.